# Align two divs side by side without distortion during window resizing

Tags: html, css

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SIGN IN</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="freshstyle.css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="header1">

</div>              

<div id="header2">   

</div>


<div class="content">
<div id="main">
<p>The December 1969 nor'easter was an intense winter storm that most notably impacted
 the Northeastern United States and southern Quebec on December 25–28.
 The multi-faceted storm system was blamed for at least 20 deaths in the United States
 and 15 in Canada. 
 After developing over Texas and spawning several damaging tornadoes in the Deep South, 
 the cyclone advanced to the Eastern Seaboard, dropping more than 1 ft (30 cm) of snow
 as far south as Washington, D.C. The nor'easter intensified and slowed as it moved into
 New England, delivering 40 inches (100 cm) of snowfall in some places, with heavy rain
 near the coast and a severe ice storm in Vermont and New Hampshire. In Canada, Montreal
 received 27.5 in (70 cm) of snow over a period of 60 hours. Equipment failures and 
 drifts up to 30 ft (9 m) left roadways blocked for many days throughout the affected 
 region, and some communities became inaccessible except by snowmobile. 
 The weight of the snow and ice, combined with gale-force winds, collapsed roofs and 
 brought down power lines. Ice jams and excessive rainfall created widespread flooding
 in eastern New England. (Full article...) </p>
</div>
<div class="sideryt">
<div id="login">
         <form action="" method="">
         <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=5 >

         <tr>
         <td>
               <label for="fname"><b>Email</b></label> </td>
               <td><input type="text" id="fname" name=""/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
               <label for="fname"><b>Password</b></label></td>
               <td><input type="text" id="fname" name=""/></td></tr>

               <tr><td colspan=2>
               <a class="button" href="">Login</a></td>          
               </tr>
               </table>
               </form>
               </div>

         <div class="create">
         <h1>Create an account</h1>
          <h2>register for free.Always!</h2></div>
         <div id="signup">
         <form action="" method="">
         <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=5 >
         <tr><td colspan=2>
               <a class="button" href="file:///S:/mini%20project%20stuff/sign_up.html">Signup</a></td>          
               </tr>
               </table>
         </form>

</div>   
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
 <div id="foot">
  <ul>
<li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">FAQS</a></li>
<li><a href="">contacts</a></li>
  </div>
copyright &copy shiv 2016
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

the sideryt div during window resizing is vertically fixed but I want it to be horizontally fixed.Also it distorts the page when window is resized.also help me with any other better solutions for fixing the sideryt div if possible.
My CSS code is here:`

```
body{
     background-color:cyan;
     margin:10px;
     font:40px;
     font-family:arial,Verdana,Times New Roman,Sans-Sherif;

}
#header1{
    margin:10px;
    font-size:45px;
     height:90px;      
     background-color:red;
         }
#header2{
         height:35px;
        margin:10px;
background-color:blue;
}
/* html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color:cyan;
} */
.content{

    overflow:auto; 
      margin: 10px;

    /*height: 100%;
    width:100%; */
    background-color:brown;
    position:relative;

        }
#main{
      background-color:yellow;
       /* display: inline-block;   */
      padding:20px;
      margin:10px;
      font-size:20px;
      font-family:arial,Verdana,Times New Roman,Sans-Sherif;
      float:left;
      display:inline;
      word-wrap: break-word;


      /* height: 100%;*/
    width:50%;
     /* display: inline;  */
     /* vertical-align:top; */


      }
.sideryt{
            display: inline;   
         vertical-align:top;
        background-color:brown; 
        font-size:105%;
        font-family:arial,Verdana,Times New Roman,Sans-Sherif;
        padding:20px;
        margin:10px;        
           /* display: inline-block;  */ 
         width:40%;
        /*height:100%; */ 
        float:right;
         /* left:0;  */
         position:fixed;
         left:53%;
              display: block;
              display:table;


        }

.button{
background: #e7e7e7;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius:5px;
text-decoration:none;
line-height: 28px;
padding: 0 10px;
text-align: center;
margin-left:130px;
box-sizing: border-box;

clear:left;
}
.fpss{
      margin-left:110px;
      text-decoration:none;
}
.create{
     line-height:150%;
     margin-left:50px;
}       

#footer{
      background-color:green;
       margin:10px;
      font-size:105%;
       clear:both;
       color:yellow;
       text-align:center
     }
     #foot  {
background-color: green;
margin: 0px;
height: 35px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 20px;
}
#foot ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
#foot li {
display: inline;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#foot a{
text-decoration:none;
color: cyan;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: white;
vertical-align:middle
}
#foot a:hover{
color: black;
background-color:white;
}

ul{
padding:0px;
list-style-type: none;
}

a{
color:#666;
text-decoration: none;

}
a:hover {
color: #000;
background-color: #dadada;
border-radius: 3px;}
```

Comment: what u what , actually i dont get your point ? do you want this div will fixed right top ?

Comment: No,I want it to be beside the main div i.e.to the right of the text but it should be fixed so that when i change the window size it doesn't overlap or distort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see ...is it helpfull for you ...
if you use any framework like bootstrap or media-query , then it will more easy . thank you and please let me know .

```css
body{
     background-color:cyan;
     margin:10px;
     font:40px;
     font-family:arial,Verdana,Times New Roman,Sans-Sherif;

}
#header1{
    margin:10px;
    font-size:45px;
     height:90px;      
     background-color:red;
         }
#header2{
         height:35px;
        margin:10px;
background-color:blue;
}

.content{

    overflow:hidden; 
      margin: 10px;
    background-color:brown;
    position:relative;

        }
#main{
      background-color:yellow;
       /* display: inline-block;   */
      padding:20px;
      margin:10px;
      font-size:20px;
      font-family:arial,Verdana,Times New Roman,Sans-Sherif;
      float:left;
      display:inline;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    width:35%;
      }
.sideryt{

         /*vertical-align:top;*/
     float : right;
        background-color:brown; 
        font-size:105%;
        font-family:arial,Verdana,Times New Roman,Sans-Sherif;
        padding:20px;
        margin:10px;        
            display: inline-block;  
         width:35%;
         position:static;
         
        }

.button{
background: #e7e7e7;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius:5px;
text-decoration:none;
line-height: 28px;
padding: 0 10px;
text-align: center;
margin-left:130px;
box-sizing: border-box;

clear:left;
}
.fpss{
      margin-left:110px;
      text-decoration:none;
}
.create{
     line-height:150%;
     margin-left:50px;
}       

#footer{
      background-color:green;
       margin:10px;
      font-size:105%;
       clear:both;
       color:yellow;
       text-align:center
     }
     #foot  {
background-color: green;
margin: 0px;
height: 35px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 20px;
}
#foot ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
#foot li {
display: inline;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#foot a{
text-decoration:none;
color: cyan;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
color: white;
vertical-align:middle
}
#foot a:hover{
color: black;
background-color:white;
}

ul{
padding:0px;
list-style-type: none;
}

a{
color:#666;
text-decoration: none;

}
a:hover {
color: #000;
background-color: #dadada;
border-radius: 3px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SIGN IN</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="freshstyle.css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="header1">

</div>              

<div id="header2">   

</div>


<div class="content">
<div id="main">
<p>The December 1969 nor'easter was an intense winter storm that most notably impacted
 the Northeastern United States and southern Quebec on December 25–28.
 The multi-faceted storm system was blamed for at least 20 deaths in the United States
 and 15 in Canada. 
 After developing over Texas and spawning several damaging tornadoes in the Deep South, 
 the cyclone advanced to the Eastern Seaboard, dropping more than 1 ft (30 cm) of snow
 as far south as Washington, D.C. The nor'easter intensified and slowed as it moved into
 New England, delivering 40 inches (100 cm) of snowfall in some places, with heavy rain
 near the coast and a severe ice storm in Vermont and New Hampshire. In Canada, Montreal
 received 27.5 in (70 cm) of snow over a period of 60 hours. Equipment failures and 
 drifts up to 30 ft (9 m) left roadways blocked for many days throughout the affected 
 region, and some communities became inaccessible except by snowmobile. 
 The weight of the snow and ice, combined with gale-force winds, collapsed roofs and 
 brought down power lines. Ice jams and excessive rainfall created widespread flooding
 in eastern New England. (Full article...) </p>
</div>
<div class="sideryt">
<div id="login">
         <form action="" method="">
         <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=5 >

         <tr>
         <td>
               <label for="fname"><b>Email</b></label> </td>
               <td><input type="text" id="fname" name=""/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
               <label for="fname"><b>Password</b></label></td>
               <td><input type="text" id="fname" name=""/></td></tr>

               <tr><td colspan=2>
               <a class="button" href="">Login</a></td>          
               </tr>
               </table>
               </form>
               </div>

         <div class="create">
         <h1>Create an account</h1>
          <h2>register for free.Always!</h2></div>
         <div id="signup">
         <form action="" method="">
         <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=5 >
         <tr><td colspan=2>
               <a class="button" href="file:///S:/mini%20project%20stuff/sign_up.html">Signup</a></td>          
               </tr>
               </table>
         </form>

</div>   
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
 <div id="foot">
  <ul>
<li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">FAQS</a></li>
<li><a href="">contacts</a></li>
  </div>
copyright &copy shiv 2016
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all thnxxx for your suggestion and the code worked too almost upto my expectation.If u would like to know my further concern I would suggest you to see facebook login page and minimise the window to minimum and see what happens.Thats exactly how I want my page to be..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
.container {
 margin: 10px;
background-color:brown;
}
.sideryt {
/*max-width: 100%;*/
width: 50%;
background:brown;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
float: right;
}
.main {
width: 50%;
background:yellow;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: sorry but that didn't work.It is giving only a part of main div

Comment: Yes,the main div can change a bit but the sideryt should be fixed

Comment: Change the width of the two div as your expectation and make the main div scrollable